# AR Modelling. Box Cox and Differencing don't give Stationary Data

Tags: forecasting, autoregressive, differencing, box-jenkins

I am trying to fit an AR/ARIMA model on [electricity data on hourly prices](https://1drv.ms/u/s!AguanZAH7qTyrXkj-EQ5IP2r4LVi?e=uFbblq) during a almost three year period, I am following the guidelines in [Hyndman, R.J., & Athanasopoulos, G. (2018)](https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html) to do this. This post is about understanding the histograms, ACF and PACF, and what the Differencing do to these graphs.

My prices are clearly not Stationary with `skewness = 4.22, kurtosis = 27.68`. (Graphs below). So, I am first applying a Box Cox transformation, since I have negative data, I add a small constant.

```
# Add constant
df1 = df.Price_REG1+2.1
# Apply Box Cox
fitted_data, fitted_lambda = stats.boxcox(df1)
# Convert to DataFrame (so I can plot)
df1 = pd.DataFrame(fitted_data)
```

This gives me a vastly improved distribution but the ACF plot still show these gradually decreasing correlations, the PACF doesn't change a lot either.

So I am thinking, that maybe I should difference the Series. So I try, both a normal difference and a seasonal difference.

```
df1diff = df1.diff()
# Diff on 24 steps, one day, (there is daily seasonality).
df1diff24 = df1.diff(24)
```

What happens then is that the kurtosis gets very high (slightly better for the `diff(24)` but still high) and the ACF plots don't show anything. Which I guess is because the data is to far from a Gaussian distribution.

If I difference again, the distribution only gets a slightly lower kurtosis.

So, I am stuck here. Do I have to use another method, like dealing with seasonality with dummies or Moving Averages, or do I miss something in this approach. Because right now I don't see a way to move forward.

The figures show the four different series with original (top-left), Box Cox (top-right), Box Cox Diff (bottom-left), Box Cox Diff 24 steps back (bottom-right).

[image]
[image][image]

Comment: Stationarity is about whether the distribution of the data changes over time, so it has nothing to do with overall skewness or kurtosis. For hourly electricity prices, I could imagine you have [tag:multiple-seasonalities], specifically within days, within weeks and within years. Have you looked at seasonplots for the different possible seasonalities? If these are present, ARIMA will have a hard time, and you may want to look at the models described in [the tag wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/multiple-seasonalities/info).

Comment: Okay. I thought I could still evaluate stationarity with histograms. So a normal distribution have nothing to do with stationarity? Yes, I have looked. I especially have clear daily and weekly seasonality. So you are saying that this approach may be at a dead end here? I will look into the TBATS and MSTL. Thank you.

Comment: Exactly. There are various flavors of "stationarity", a strong one being that $(X_t, \dots, X_{t+k})$ and $(X_{t+n}, \dots, X_{t+n+k})$ have the same joint distribution. *What* that distribution is is irrelevant for stationarity. So IID fat-tailed data is stationary (and may have high skewness or kurtosis), while seasonal data with normal noise is nonstationary. I would indeed assume that TBATS/MSTL is more useful in your case than ARIMA. There is also vibrant research in [electricity price forecasting](https://forecasting-encyclopedia.com/practice.html#Electricity_price_forecasting)